# what is the difference between using drupal_add_js and ['#attached']

Tags: 7, javascript

What is the difference between `drupal_add_js()` and `$form['#attached']['js'][]` ? 
When is the purpose of using each of the above functions?

(I mean I know that it is used to attached js to say form if used inside form but when is `drupal_add_js` used and when is `$form['#attached']['js'][]` used ?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `drupal_add_js()` in your form building function, you are attaching JavaScript to a page, and that's it.

If you are using `$form['#attached']['js']`, other modules may interact, test and change it as they need, using `hook_form_alter()`. That's the way you should choose every time your JavaScript is functionally related to particular form.

Other than that, they are functionally the same.

**Note** that it is usually better to use [JavaScript libraries](https://drupal.org/node/756722#javascript-libraries) than plain JavaScript files, as they allows you to declare versions, keep relations between JS and CSS, manage dependencies, well, they are generally way more powerful.

Of course then you should use `$form['#attached']['library']` when your JavaScript Library is functionally related to particular form, and only use `drupal_add_library()` when no form is in any way related to library's function.

Comment: So to alter node page (node/[nid]) one should use drupal_add_js and for node_form (node/add) one should use $form['#attached']['js'] ..Am I right ?

Comment: Also what about blocks?

Comment: @harshal Yes. Unless your JS on node/add is not related to a node add form and works on elements that does not belong to that form. Then use drupal_add_js as usual.

Comment: @harshal corrected already. Sometimes I think faster than I type, sorry.

Comment: @Mołot You're gonna love this...`drupal_add_js()` should not be used, wherever physically possible `#attached` should be used instead. My source? Same as the source form the discussion we were having the other day :D [Link to related d.o issue](https://drupal.org/node/1737148)

Comment: 'Unles your JS on node/add is not related to a node add form and works on elements that does not belong to that form' Can u clarify this a little bit I did not get it

Comment: if I have to add js to the node/[nid] page then drupal_add_js() will work ???

Comment: @harshal I meant that if your javascript operates, for example, on footer or sidebar that happens to be on the same page as form, but have nothing to do with that form, I don't see a reason to attach it to a form. Especially that there may be many forms on one page - to which one would you attach form-unrelated js then ;) ? Of course Clive's sources may say different, I don't claim I'm some kind of oracle.

Comment: can u please answer this in YES or NO  
if I have to add js to the node/[nid] page (i.e. a template for node i guess node.tpl.php) then will drupal_add_js()  work ???

Comment: @harshal Never put `drupal_add_js()` in a template file, it will break things when caching/aggregation is turned on

Comment: @Clive is now my answer consistent with linked issue? Or am I still  missing something?

Comment: Oh I wasn't saying your answer was wrong (wouldn't have upvoted it if I did), but yes I think that covers it. I was just doing the drive-by "I've been told this has caveats" thing that I apparently do now ;)

Comment: @Clive Well, with libraries over naked JS I agree, and I should have point it out in the first place. I'm using them since my issues with jQuery Multi. Just wanted to be sure my answer full and exhaust the topic.