# How to send variable to the javascript in Drupal?

Tags: forms

What is the easiest way to send a value from PHP to Javascript in Drupal form?

Comment: Referring to the answers, drupal_add_js is deprecated. You should use #attached for forwards-compatibility. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90040/what-is-the-difference-between-using-drupal-add-js-and-attached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Drupal is with [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7), using the "setting" type, e.g.:

```
drupal_add_js(array('variableName' => 'value'), 'setting');
```

That will make the variable available on the JS side at `Drupal.settings.variableName`.